# Convert file permissions in Bash

Tags: bash, permissions

Is there a simple way to convert file permissions?

For Example:

```
if [ filePermission = -rw-r--r-- ]
then 
    echo 644
fi
if [ filePermission = -r-xr-xr-x ]
then
    echo 555
fi

  # etc..
```

I'm not trying to change the permissions, just look at the octal value.

Something like this:

```
-bash-4.1$ ls -l test*
-rw-r--r-- 1 user joe 0 Nov  11 09:41 test1
-r-xr-xr-x 1 user joe 0 Nov  11 10:12 test2*
-r--r----- 1 user joe 0 Nov  11 10:14 test3
-rwxr-x--- 1 user joe 0 Nov  11 10:17 test4*
-bash-4.1$ ./perm test*
test1:
permissions: 644
test2:
permissions: 555
test3:
permissions: 440
test4:
permissions: 750
```

Comment: You can change file permissions with the `chmod` command - is this what you are after? Your question is a bit unclear on what you want to do - currently you echo the octal permission of a string stating the permissions in rwx format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to print the the octal representation for a given file, `stat` can help:

```
stat --printf '%a' your_file
```

Comment: This works but how do you store the Octal in a variable? `value=stat --printf '%a' your_file` ?